# Android Studio: custom dialog only re-occurs if no is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialog, rating

Okay so I have this message popup that asks the user to kindly rate the app. They can choose Yes or No. If Yes is pressed, the app in the app store will be opened. If no is pressed, the dialog box closes (for now). I want it so that if Yes is pressed, the dialog box will no longer ever show (even if the user only presses yes but does not actually rate the app..) even after they close and re-open the app. 
The purpose of this is so that the user doesn't keep getting asked to rate the app even when they may have already done that.

Dialog Class:

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes, no;

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_yes:

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en"));
            getContext().startActivity(intent);

            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_no:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
  }
}
```

(I know the link is for pokemon go lol its just for trial purposes.)
any help will be greatly appreciated :)

________edit_______
code where i show the dialog (occurs when the user enters a specific class):

```
 public class Final1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.final1);
    CustomDialogClass cdd=new CustomDialogClass(Final1.this);
    cdd.show();
```

Comment: can you post the code where you show your dialog.

Comment: I have added that. It just always shows when the user is in that specific class.

Comment: The second code I added was wrong.. It was for something else, sorry. I have removed it

Comment: If you put `cdd.show()` in `onCreate()`, every time you enter the `Activity`, the dialog shows. You need a variable to mark whether the dialog should come to user.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to store a state about whether the user pressed `YES` button. And before you want to show your dialog, check the state.

Since you only need a Boolean value, `SharedPreferences` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks but I'm kind of a noob so I'm not so sure how to approach that. I tried different things but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if I could see where you show the actual dialog box, the code you provide for that only goes to the market page again... but we can still work with this.

If you want to never show this box to the user again, I recommend using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). This will enable us to store (basically) permanent variables.

Example:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("your-app", 0);
if(settings.getBoolean("btn_pressed", false)){
//show dialog
}
```

This will make sure the dialog doesn't open if we have the Shared Preferences boolean "btn_pressed" set to true.

To set this boolean after the yes button is pressed:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_yes:
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = c.getSharedPreferences("your-app", 0).edit();
            edit.putBoolean("btn_pressed", true);
            edit.apply();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en"));
            getContext().startActivity(intent);

            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_no:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}
```

Shared Preferences is an easy way for your app to remember permanent user settings or things of this nature. Hope this helps!

EDIT: please note syntax correction, the editor has a capital (SharedPreferences.editor becomes SharedPreferences.Editor)

Comment: Thanks however i get the errors: cannot resolve editor, putboolean, and apply.

Comment: same with getBoolean